# Bootstrap: Centering a set of columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
...
...
  </div>
</div>
```

I want those 8 small columns to float in the middle of the available page width. If I add a col-sm-offset-2 but that just pushed everything right, even if there wasn't space. Advice?

Answer (score 2):

If you encompass your `row` in a [container](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container), it should center everything. So that, with the `col-sm-offset-2` should achieve what you want, e.g.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
       ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't exactly centered though. I end up with a lot more space on the right than on the left. I deployed it to heroku in a test form for you to inspect...http://teemroom.herokuapp.com/test/daniel

Comment: Up your offset from `col-sm-offset-1` to `col-sm-offset-2`, the grid is 12 columns, not 10. Try that.